# How can I insert data into a SQL Server Express database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-express

How can I add data into a SQL Server Express database?

I have written the following code

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
 conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;" 
    +"User Instance=true;" +  "Integrated Security=true;" 
    +  "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|GCdatabase.mdf;";
 conn.Open();
 //...
 conn.Close();
```

Is this right?

If yes then how can I add data into table ?

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials about this in the googlewebs. And books in the amazons.

Comment: i not able to get proper example that's y i have asked

Comment: You need to work on your google-fu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing that. One of them is using a `SqlCommand` object with an `insert` SQL statement:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString(/* your connection string goes here */);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into table values (1, 2, 3)", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: ya it excurte query but data is not get added

Comment: @bkac: Did you change the insert statement to match your table name and field types?

Answer (score 3):

```
        string connstring = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;" +
                             "User Instance=true;" +
                             "Integrated Security=true;" +
                             "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|GCdatabase.mdf;";
        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO Table " +
                          "(Column1, Column2) VALUES " +
                          "(@Column2, @Column2); SELECT @@identity;";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = insertSql;

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Column1", Column1));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Column2", Column2));

            connection.Open();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: using (SqlConnection connection* = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) * show error

Comment: +1 only answer so far that uses **parametrized query** to avoid SQL injection!